# T-SQL If condition inside select

Tags: sql, sql-server, msbi

I have a condition where there are multiple scenarios and I need to check each scenario. I need to concatenate the result if two or more cases matches.

What I thought was , using CASE statement but i am unable to concatenate multiple scenarios using CASE statement.

So what I am doing now is , using if statement . Below is the query i did:

```
declare @result varchar(200)
set @result=''

;with cte as
(
select * from table 1
)

if(column 1=5) set @result=@result+'case1'
if(column 2=6) set @result=@result+'case2'
if(column 3=7) set @result=@result+'case3'
if(column 4=10) set @result=@result+'case4'


select *,@result from cte
```

So here, i need to use Select statement right after CTE but i cannot use IF/ELSE statement in select statement . But also i cannot use the CASE Statement with variable concatenate.

So the result should be like :

```
id | column 1 | column 2| column 3| column 4| Result
-----------------------------------------------------
 3 |   5      |   6     |   6     |   9      | case1;`case2
 4 |   4      |   7     |   7     |   10     | case2
 5 |   5      |   6     |   6     |   10     | case1;`case2; case4
 6 |   5      |   6     |   7     |   10     | case2;case2;case3;case4
 7 |   4      |   5     |   6     |   3      | No Result
```

Anyone could help me to complete this ?

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you want.  Are you trying to make the values in each row the cumulative result of all the preceding rows, by continuously concatenating to the same string?  I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve.  Please give example input data and the result you want from that example data : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yes, I have updated the question with needed output in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate multiple CASEs in a single SELECT:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'Case1' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN 2=2 THEN 'Case2' ELSE '' END
+ CASE ...
```

EDIT based on comments:  If, as you say, your broken code using `IF` really would solve your issue, then there is no issue, since the `if` statements you used don't need to be in the SELECT at all.   You could simply do this:

```
declare @result varchar(200)
set @result=''

if(1=1) set @result=@result+'case1'
if(2=2) set @result=@result+'case2'


;with cte as
(
select * from table 1
)
select *,@result from cte
```

EDIT based on the update to original question:

So my first solution is correct.   The additional details in your question allow me to make it a little more clear.   By the way you can't use a variable at all for this:

```
;with cte as
(
select * ,
CASE WHEN column1=5 THEN 'case1' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN column2=6 THEN 'case2' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN column3=7 THEN 'case3' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN column4=10 THEN 'case4' ELSE '' END AS result
from table 1
)
select *,
CASE WHEN result='' THEN 'No Result Found' ELSE result END as result 
from cte
```

Note that if you need to separate the values with semi-colons (as shown in your question) you can put a semi-colon before each value (example `';case3'`), and in the final SELECT, use STUFF() to remove the first semi-colon.

Comment: No , I tried this one but this one doesn't help my case. I donot need Else because when one case doesnot match i need to go for another case instead of printing the value of else . My Case is exactly matched by If condition , but i cannot use If inside Select

Comment: Thank you , I saw the edited result , I again tried that already but the problem is , the values I put in IF statement comes from CTE, so i need to put IF statement below CTE.

Comment: Also at the end of the CASE if none of case match i need to put 'No case found' in Result column.

Comment: I have updated the Question now , i cannot use the first solution because i need to check every cases and give No Result Found at the end if none of cases matches

Comment: Sorry to say but it doesn't worked too because Column 1, column 2 .. comes from CTE only and then only i can used those column in case statement so .

Comment: Ok, so NOW you're saying that column 1 is created by the CTE and does not exist in the table.  yet another thing you should have said in your original question, but my solution still works, you just have to use a second CTE that selects from the first CTE, and then the final SELECT is from the second CTE.

Comment: But when i used your solution , then when first case didnt matched and  second case match , it gives the null result instead of giving second result

Comment: Then you didn't implement it correctly.  If you got NULL, then you probably didn't use the `ELSE ''` like I posted.   Edit your question and show the exact code you used.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT * FROM table1
)
SELECT *,(
    CASE
        WHEN Column1 <> 5 AND Column2 <> 6 AND Column3 <> 7 AND Column4 <> 10 THEN 'No Result'
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN Column1 = 5 THEN 'Case 1;' ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN Column2 = 6 THEN 'Case 2;' ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN Column3 = 7 THEN 'Case 3;' ELSE '' END +
            CASE WHEN Column4 = 10 THEN 'Case 4;' ELSE '' END
        END
)Result
FROM cte



| id | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |                       Result |
|----|---------|---------|---------|---------|------------------------------|
|  3 |       5 |       6 |       6 |       9 |               Case 1;Case 2; |
|  4 |       4 |       7 |       7 |      10 |               Case 3;Case 4; |
|  5 |       5 |       6 |       6 |      10 |        Case 1;Case 2;Case 4; |
|  6 |       5 |       6 |       7 |      10 | Case 1;Case 2;Case 3;Case 4; |
|  7 |       4 |       5 |       6 |       9 |                    No Result |
```

[Check SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d649c/2)